# Annoying Problem Encountered : momentjs taking a day off by 1 with mat-datepicker for different timezones?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, momentjs, angular-moment

**Scenario: 
On load of a component everything works fine. Date doesn't get off by 1.
but after i change the date using mat-datepicker or manually the date is off by 1.**

I can see its a timezone issue. with -4:00 offset timezone it is giving me the wrong behaviour but in my timezone its works fine(+5:30).

[image]

Please Help!

HTML:

```
<input id="startDatePicker" matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" [(ngModel)]="model.start" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form__dateInput"/>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
```

ModelClass file:

```
export class Query {
    start = moment();
    end = moment();


    public toParams(): HttpParams {
     let params = new HttpParams();
     start.local();
     end.local();
     this.start.startOf('day');
     this.end.endOf('day'); 
     params = params.set('start', this.start.toISOString());
     params = params.set('end', this.end.toISOString());
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default behaviour to parse dates as UTC by providing the MAT_MOMENT_DATA_ADAPTER_OPTIONS and setting it to useUtc: true.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatMomentDateModule],
providers: [
{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }
]
})
```

Comment: tried that already but still it ain't working with this configuration